# Products not showing anymore

Tags: product, magento-1.9

I'm setting up a new Magento store and the products aren't displayed anymore. They were showing before and I haven't made big changes lately (mostely CSS)
The images were also not showing anymore, but I fixed that by renaming the .htaccess

I've done the following things:

- Status > enabled
- Visibility > Catalog, Search
- Qty > 123
- Stock Availability > In Stock
- Is assigned to right category
- Category is active
- Disabled cache
- Reindexed indices

There are no Associated Products because it are Simple Products

The strange thing is, that when I navigate directly to the product it show a blank page.
The console does show a prototype error, but that was also there when the products were showing. Here it is anyway:
    **The error**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
```

**The line it refers to**

```
var respondersForEvent = registry.get(eventName);
```

Does anybody know how I can get my products back?

Comment: So there is no html regarding the products at all on the product page? Does the rest of the page display correctly (header, footer...etc)?

Comment: Nope, nothing shows on the product page. I just noticed the console shows a `500 (Internal Server Error)`
`GET /producten/grind-en-split/grind.html 500 (Internal Server Error) `

Comment: check your Apache error.log then, therte must be something wrong.

Comment: Did you check the Magernto system and exception logs? Do they say something relevant?

Comment: I checked the system.log file and the error was caused by not terminating a comment in a layout file. The products and the product page are now showing again

Comment: good. I suggest you post an answer to your own question and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem by looking in the error files, as suggested in the comments.
The problem was that I had not terminated a comment in my layout.xml